# When is .stroke() required after .clearRect()?

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas, 2d

I have several places in my charting code where `.clearRect()` doesnt have any effect, unless I call `.stroke()` on the next line. At first I thought I forgot to close some path somewhere, but I doublechecked that is not the case.

What could be a logical explanation for this behaviour, or is a call to `.stroke()` required by the specifications?

Comment: It looks more like a bug specific to your code. Could you show the (or one at least) several draw functions you talk about ?

Answer (score 0):

Without code to see what you are actually doing it is hard to tell what goes wrong.

But no, stroke is not required and is not related to clearRect.

Here are some generic points to consider:

- `stroke()` will only *rasterize* the outline of an *existing* path. If there is no path there won't be anything to stroke.
- `clearRect()` does not work on paths but only on the bitmap itself. It is not related to `stroke()` or any other path operations. Clearing the bitmap does not clear the path.
- A *path* is cleared (reset) by calling `beginPath()` but does not clear anything in the bitmap
- `closePath()` is only required if you want to connect first point with the last point (ends the loop) and must be called before path is rasterized using `stroke()` to have an effect (`fill()` on the other hand will implicitly and temporary close the path for you as it cannot fill an open path - this goes for `clip()` as well just to mention it).
- Clearing a canvas means all pixels in the region that is being cleared are set to black color and fully transparent.
- `clearRect()` is affected by transforms.

If you call clearRect() and does not reset the path (with beginPath) and then call stroke you will rasterize what is existing on the path.

If you intention is to animate somwthing then you can consider the following routine:

1. Clear canvas (`clearRect()`)
2. Clear path (`beginPath()`)
3. Define path with current coordinates (arc, line, rect etc.)
4. Rasterize path (`stroke()` or `fill()`)
5. Loop using `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout`/`setInterval` depending on your update frequency.

Comment: @GameAlchemist where do you get this from? you should provide some references where this is documented (GC behavior in particular and the need for a closePath). #000000 *is* black transparent color and is what the specification uses: "**2. Clear the pixels in pixels to a fully transparent black**" [source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-clearrect). I cannot find anything in the specs confirming what you say.. please help out here.

Comment: @GameAlchemist here are the specs BTW, [beginPath and closePath](www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-beginpath). I still cannot find anything here saying closePath is needed for beginPath in any case... any comment?

Comment: (a typo in my comment, cannot edit it, #000000 for transparent black was of course intended to be notated as 0x00000000. Point still remain though).

Comment: You guys are fierce today :)  I suspect "behind the scenes" clearRect quickly zero-fills the imageData array--unintentionally setting each pixel to black and intentionally setting each pixel transparent.  I couldn't resist this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/aUSxS/

Comment: @markE you'd say? hehe :) Thanks for the fiddle! I *did* intend a calm tone though - text can be hard!.. :)

Comment: We are the 3 old guys always there in the back of the bar, and looking at strangers with suspicious eyes : 'Did you save your context, kiddo ??' :-) Let's call it the 'Canvas Café' :-) @markeE : a transparent pixel has no color, so to speak : it is transparent. I couldn't see anything strange in your jsbin. Ken : the color thing, is just a phrasing detail. For the performance thing, i know the specs says the contrary, it's just from my experience. Too bad i couldn't exhibit it with a fiddle, it's quite hard to measure g.c.'s, which might happen any time after creating the garbage anyway...